# Calling main method from another application

Tags: java, command-line

I'm writing a wrapper application that will be used to provide an abstraction layer around an existing application that is currently called from the command line. How would I go about calling the main method in the existing app from within my wrapper app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java main methods are static, so you could just call it as:

```
import other.app.package.name;

...

String[] args;
// Create/populate args here
ClassNameHere.main(args);
```

Of course, this is assuming you looked at the other application's manifest file to see which class main resides in.

Set `args` to whatever you would usually pass in on the command line.

Comment: Also include possible command line arguments (entered as an array of strings).

Comment: @Kathy: I was just adding something in when you said that.  I hadn't thought about main taking a String array when I originally posted.

Comment: Note that if you need to isolate/differentiate the classes used by the application, you should load the application class through a dedicated classloader and then reflect over the Class instance to obtain main method.